# How to get value from async function in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asynchronous, asyncstorage

```
function CategoryCard (props) {

    const [done, setDone] = React.useState(null);
    let check;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function checkData() {
            check = await getData(props.path);
            // prints CORRECTLY
            console.log(check);
        }
        checkData();
    //prints INCORRECTLY
        console.log(check);
        setDone(true);
    }, []);

    return (

        <View>
        {done ? (
            <Text>{check}</Text>
        ):(
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#99ff99" />
            </View>
        )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

How can I get a value from an async function into my regular function in react-native?
In the above code, the first console.log prints the expected values, but the second one gives undefined, as if the async function never had any effect on the variable check.
I need the value of check from `getData(props.path)` in order to display it in the `<Text>` component.

Any ideas?

Comment: put your data in state and update the state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it in the state.

```
function CategoryCard (props) {

    const [check, setCheck] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function checkData() {
            const data = await getData(props.path);
            setCheck(data);
        }
        checkData();

    }, []);

    return (

        <View>
        {check ? (
            <Text>{check}</Text>
        ):(
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#99ff99" />
            </View>
        )}
        </View>
    );
}
```